# Should AWS Redshift be used for online querying?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, rds

I have an use case where a fairly massive (greater than 1 TB) SQL DB has to be moved to cloud and I was thinking of using Redshift instead of some RDS solution since it is a bit cheaper and I am fine with handling latencies less than 10 seconds for my queries. The application will query the DB very rarely - about 100 times a day.

Would going with Redshift be a reasonable option seeing the cost savings compared to RDS?

Update: The system will update the DB once or twice per day.

Comment: You have mentioned that you would rarely query the system. But please mention whether the system will be modified using an update or an insert statement? The answer will be heavily dependent on whether you go for inserts / updates or not.

Comment: @YusufHassan Sorry. I should had included that. I have updated the question to specify that the DB would be updated once or twice per day.

Comment: Please accept my answer below if it helped you to achieve what you were looking for. This way, it won't be lost in thread and would help others who have similar issues :)

Answer (score 4):

The argument about what will be best for your business will always be there and the best decisions will be better taken by you considering all the costs and performance tradeoffs, but with all my experience and the information provided by you above, I can confidently let you know about the impact the below actions will have:

> 1. Who'll write to the Redshift tables?

If the data is not real time, you may go ahead with Redshift. But  if you need real-time data or your other metrics are dependent on it, such as showing balance or loyalty credit points, then Redshift is not the ideal bet. Ideally load the data when the CPU usage is at its least.

> 2. Write operations are painfully slow in Redshift

Being columnar, it is expected that bulk writes will be painstakingly slow. Therefore, if you insert the data, make sure if happens over mid-night so that CPU is not consumed in ETL tasks.

> 3. What dataset will be queried?

If the dataset is OLAP, then Redshift is ideal. If the data is OLTP, then there won't be a performance merit in switching to, although it might save some cost. And it will be a pain point when your business grows

What we need to understand is that Amazon Redshift is not similar to any row based data warehouse. It's used for analytical purposes. If you're generating bulk data (in millions for a day) and you need to query it, then it's the tool for you. Companies use Amazon Redshift for cohorting, user behaviour and trend analysis since this involves querying a huge dataset. Columnar databases are used to query millions of records since the columnar orientation is optimised for querying mammoth dataset.

If you're storing OLTP datasets, such as users created, orders placed, order attributes, preferences, balance etc etc, then amazon Redshift is not the tool for you. Writes will be slow and you'll not see any performance improvement in query such a small OLTP dataset.

Moreover, if your architecture has a `Master - Slave` configuration, you CANNOT bear any delay and using RS will cause delays in data migration to slave since it is not optimised for write operations. Slave is expected to be a replica of master, containing almost real time data and using RS for this architecture will cause useless delays.

Whereas if you capture user behaviour, click and gestures, angle of mobile, lat / long of his visits... anything that generates data in bulk and you'll query the huge dataset for analytical purposes, then Redshift is the tool for you. Such data points are not required real-time and can be loaded once or twice a day.

I would suggest that go for Redshift only if you see an improvement in performance. If you switch only for cost saving measures and your business escalates in the future, it'll be a huge task for you to again migrate to an appropriate architecture.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like based on your use case Redshift could be a great fit. Redshift is more of a OLAP as opposed to OLTP database. In non-database language, it's more meant for real-time inserts or reads (real-time being sub-second). Redshift also would have much lower concurrency than something like RDS, but that also doesn't sound like it's a strong need for you.

RDS would make sense if you needed:

- real-time single record inserts
- sub-second queries
- up to thousands of queries executing per second.

Because you can handle query times over 1 second, but under 10 and your query workload isn't too heavy Redshift should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

AWS already position Redshift clearly : it is mean for database warehousing.

In short, AWS expect the admin :

- massage the database according to database warehouse need
- Know how to shard/partitioning the database
- Know how to optimised the database, e.g. denormalised if required(i.e. transform or migrate tables from OLTP(OnLine Transaction processing) friendly to OLAP(OnLine Analytical processing) friendly.
- You may need more disk space when moving to Redshift, because it will create additional indexes for internal optimisation.

In short, moving to redshift **maybe or maybe not** give you any cost and/or performance advantages.  It is NOT magic bullet.